# SQL Server Network Configuration Tab is missing. Can't enable TP/IP Protocols

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2022, tcpip

I am using SQL Server 2022 and the "SQL Server configuration manager" is not visible.[image: SQL Configuration Manager]

Further more I opened "Services and Applications" and in computer management and SQL Server is not showing even though I have multiple instances of SQL Server 2022 installed on my system.

[image: Computer Management]

I have tried to remove the servers but it says I don't have apps associated with sql server so I can't uninstall it.

[image: Uninstall error]

I have searched everything on the web for last 2 days but of no use. Please someone help me in this regard. In SQL Server Management Studio, the server is connected but due to no part available, the backend of my express.js is not connecting to the server.

[image: Error in VS Code]

Comment: I am confused, your screenshots seem counter to what you've stated. "*"SQL Server configuration manager" is not visible.*" - But you've posted a screenshot of it. The Services and Applications screenshot is too high level. If you open up Services, do you see the SQL Server service running?

Comment: @J.D. I have stated "SQL Server Network Configuration Tab is missing". It is a Tab in SQL Server Configuration Manager (of which I have provided screenshots of ) that allows us to enable/disable and provide a PORT for TCP/IP Connections.

Comment: I literally quoted your Post's body, and this is exactly what it says: "*I am using SQL Server 2022 and the "SQL Server configuration manager" is not visible.*". But I understand what you're referring to now that you clarified. Also, I think you missed my question: "*If you open up Services, do you see the SQL Server service running?*"

Comment: @J.D. My apologies. Yes, I have seen the SQL Server Services and they are running